# How does coffee affect blood sugar levels?

Tags: caffeine, coffee, yeast-infection, blood-sugar

My girlfriend has a question:

Trying to figure out (on my own) if I have a problem with my blood sugar. To that effect I have just bought a home testing kit to run post-meal sugar test (like they would in a clinic).

Just wondering if coffee affects my blood sugar as I'd like to drink it with my `70 grams` carbs for the test.

I have a recurrent yeast infection, which is why I'm doing this testing. However I know that I don't have the following: HIV, leukemia which leaves diabetes as the only other *usual* cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a type 1 diabetic I have noticed even black coffee can have an effect on blood sugar. Coffee( the caffeine really) increases your blood epinephrine (adrenaline) levels. Adrenaline has the same effect as glucagon .[They stimulate the breakdown of glycogen into glucose](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22429/)